# Resize image when uploading with Pillow using ModelForm

Tags: django, django-forms, django-rest-framework

Hey I have a following code but, it return no error but the image is not being resized, at the beginning it was 6.2 MB and after running the code it is the same:

My model:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    user_name= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    photo= models.ImageField()
    photo_name= models.TextField(max_length=300)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.photo_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('photo:add_photo',{'pk':self.pk})
```

my Model.Form

```
class PhotoForm(ModelForm):

    def clean_image(self):
        img = self.cleaned_data.get('photo')
        if not img:
            return img
        maxdim = 1024
        if any(dim > maxdim for dim in img.image.size):
            # Resize too large image up to the max_size
            i = Image.open(img.file)
            fmt = i.format.lower()
            i.thumbnail((maxdim, maxdim))
            # We must reset io.BytesIO object, otherwise resized image bytes
            # will get appended to the original image
            img.file = type(img.file)()
            i.save(img.file, fmt)
        return img

    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        exclude= ('user_name',)
```

My views.py

```
class PhotoCreateView(View):
    form_class =  PhotoForm
    template_name = 'photo/photo_form.html'

    def get(self,request):
        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(request,self.template_name,{'form': form})
    def post(self,request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST, request.FILES)


        if form.is_valid():

            return redirect('travel:main')

        return render(request, self.template_name,{})
```

Anyone knows why it returns no error but still the image has a same size. I want to upload my images on my app which is hosted on pythonanywhere.com and they have a limit of 512 MB storage which is not a lot.

Comment: `1024x1024` isn't much small, is it?

Comment: yes, i tried with the smaller sizes and didn't work either. I mainly care about the size of the picture, my main goal is to compress it without losing much of the quality

Comment: how is PhotoForm calling `clean_image`? do you mean `clean_photo`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a package which save images with different size and label you determined, you can use `django-stdimage` package and use them like :

models.py:

```
image = StdImageField(upload_to=upload_to, blank=True, variations={
        'large': (600, 400),
        'thumbnail': (100, 100, True),
        'medium': (300, 200),
    })
```

some.html:

```
 <a href="{{ object.myimage.url }}"><img src="{{ object.myimage.thumbnail.url }}"/></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use resize method instead of thumbnail like this:

```
def clean_image(self):
        img = self.cleaned_data.get('photo')
        if not img:
            return img
        maxdim = 1024
        if any(dim > maxdim for dim in img.image.size):
            # Resize too large image up to the max_size
            i = Image.open(img.file)
            img = i.resize((maxdim, maxdim), Image.ANTIALIAS)

            img.save(image/file/path)
        return img
```